# Extracting string after second underscore and before dot R

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to keep strings after the second underscore and before dot. Thanks!

```
x <- "Exche_log_group_2.csv", "Exche_log_group_3.csv"
```

Desired output:

```
group_2  group_3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `gsub`

```
gsub("[^_]+_[^_]+_|\\..*", "", x)
[1] "group_2" "group_3"
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried ```sub("^[^_]*_", "", x)``` , not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub` with a capture group we can try:

```r
x <- c("Exche_log_group_2.csv", "Exche_log_group_3.csv")
output <- sub(".*?([^_]+_\\d+)\\.[^.]+$", "\\1", x)
output  # [1] "group_2" "group_3"
```